# Having a trouble with my logic?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, logic

I am trying to implement the elevator algorithm Shortest-Seek-Time-First.

here is my logic for determining what queue to insert into, as well as what is the current direction. However I am getting problems for instance if I am in the forward direction at position 4 and request a move to 2... Using the SSTF moving in one direction, since it is moving forward it is suppose to insert 2 into the reverse queue and keep moving forward, until the forward q  is empty.

```
string direction,requestIsIn,currDStr;
bool success= true;

cout << "Do the EnqRequest function."<<endl;
cout <<endl<<endl;
cout <<"Enter a New Track Number"<<endl;
cin >> newTrackNum;

if ( newTrackNum >= 0 && newTrackNum <= 9 )
{
    item.SetSerialNum(serialNumber);
    item.SetTrackRequest(newTrackNum);

    if ( currDir )
    {
        pRequest=forward.peek();
    }
    else
    {
        pRequest=reverse.peek();
    }

    if ( currP >= item.GetTrackRequest() && ! reverse.PQueueIsEmpty() )
    {
        direction="Reverse";
        item.SetDirection( false );
    }
    else if ( currP < item.GetTrackRequest() && ! forward.PQueueIsEmpty() )
    {
        item.SetDirection( true );
        direction="Forward";
    }
    else
    {
        if (item.GetDirection())
        {
            direction="Forward";
        }
        else
        {
            direction="REVERSE";
        }
    }

    if ( pRequest.GetDirection() && item.GetDirection() )
    {
        if ( item.GetTrackRequest() > pRequest.GetTrackRequest() )
        {
            requestIsIn="Forward Queue";

            cout<<"Inserting in forward queue"<<endl;
            serialNumber++;

            item.SetSerialNum(serialNumber);
            forward.PQueueInsertMin(item, success);

            cout<<"1st case forward"<<endl;
        }
        else if ( item.GetTrackRequest()== pRequest.GetTrackRequest() )
        {
            //&& item.GetSerialNum()>pRequest.GetSerialNum()

            requestIsIn="Forward Queue";

            cout<<"Inserting in forward queue"<<endl;
            serialNumber++;

            item.SetSerialNum(serialNumber);
            forward.PQueueInsertMin(item, success);

            cout<<"2nd case forward"<<endl;
        }
        else if ( item.GetTrackRequest() < pRequest.GetTrackRequest() && ! forward.PQueueIsEmpty() )
        {
            requestIsIn="Forward Queue";

            cout<<"Inserting in forward queue"<<endl;
            serialNumber++;

            item.SetSerialNum(serialNumber);
            forward.PQueueInsertMin(item, success);

            cout<<"1st case forward"<<endl;
        }
        else
        {
            requestIsIn="Reverse Queue";

            cout<<"Inserting in Reverse queue"<<endl;
            serialNumber++;
            item.SetSerialNum(serialNumber);

            reverse.PQueueInsert(item,success );

            cout<<"3rd case forward"<<endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if ( item.GetTrackRequest() < pRequest.GetTrackRequest() )
        {
            requestIsIn="Reverse Queue";

            cout<<"Inserting in Reverse Queue"<<endl;
            serialNumber++;

            item.SetSerialNum(serialNumber);

            reverse.PQueueInsert(item, success);
            cout<<"1st case Reverse"<<endl;
        }
        else if ( item.GetTrackRequest() == pRequest.GetTrackRequest() && item.GetSerialNum() > pRequest.GetSerialNum() )
        {
            requestIsIn="Reverse Queue";

            cout<<"Inserting in Reverse Queue"<<endl;
            serialNumber++;

            item.SetSerialNum(serialNumber);

            reverse.PQueueInsert(item, success);
            cout<<"2nd case Reverse"<<endl;
        }
        else
        {
            requestIsIn="Forward Queue";

            cout<<"Inserting in Forward queue"<<endl;
            serialNumber++;
            item.SetSerialNum(serialNumber);

            forward.PQueueInsertMin(item, success);
            cout<<"3rd case Reverse"<<endl;
        }
    }

    cout <<"EnqRequest   "<<newTrackNum<<endl;
    cout << endl << endl;
    cout <<"Current Position: .............."<<currP<<endl;
    cout <<"Current Direction: ............."<<direction<<endl;
    cout <<"Request was Enqueued in the: ..."<<requestIsIn<<endl;
    cout <<"Number of Request is: ......"<<serialNumber<<endl;
    cout <<"==================================="<<endl;
```

Comment: Your code is too big. Step through it using a debugger to isolate the problem. If you can't fix that isolated problem, ask here again.

Comment: One thing that seems odd is that you use both `direction="Reverse";` and `direction="REVERSE";`. Is that ok?

Comment: Do I see _seven_ separate `serialNumber++;
            item.SetSerialNum(serialNumber);` where one `item.SetSerialNum(++serialNumber);` should do fine? (Using a callable `trace()` would beat hard-coded inserts into `cout`.) (And what is `track`?)